# Word similar to well-read but in the context of songs

Tags: single-word-requests, music, equivalence

> He is well-read in romantic literature and his brother is ....... in blues songs.

Is there a word that can be used to convey the same idea as "well-read" but in the context of songs? In other words, what is one word for "someone who has heard a lot of songs and knows each of them very well". I am looking for a word that is specific to songs like "well-read" is for books. I know well-versed, knowledgeable, etc. are usable words here but they are not what I am looking for.

Ideally, I would like to say, "He is well-read and his brother is well-<...>." The sentence should convey that "he" reads while "his brother" listens to songs.

Comment: It would actually be interesting to find such a word. But for the irony, I like "well-versed".

Comment: I suppose it's not overly precise, but "musical" could work. From OED: *3. Skilled or trained in music; having a natural aptitude for learning or performing music; fond of music.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is not what I am looking for. Musical could mean that a person is good at performing while well-read does not convey any skill in writing. I need a word that conveys only that a person has heard a lot of songs and nothing more. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I completely agree with you; I just put it out there for the slight chance it could work.

Comment: I was on the point of asking this question - for music generally, not just songs - and have found yours.  The obvious analogy is *well heard*, or *well listened*.   But what you tend to hear is that someone 'knows' so much music, or 'has listened to' so much music.  Or even that someone is 'very knowledgeable' about music.  None of these is what I want, which is a neat way of saying that someone has listened and reflected upon a wide variety of music....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Aficionado* is an apt term to define the person within the context and it gives the emphasis on having the knowledge in a particular subject, and is often used in musical context and with music genres. Here is a very similar example to yours:

> A music lover by age 3, Boyd listened to his Vienna-trained grandmother play Brahms on the piano. Then, with Princeton pal Geoff Muldaur, he became a teenage **aficionado of blues** and jazz records.
>
> [*seattletimes.com*](https://www.seattletimes.com/entertainment/a-musical-memoir-from-one-of-the-great-record-producers-of-the-60s/)

*[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aficionado)* definition:

> If someone is an aficionado of something, they like it and know a lot about it. 
> *I happen to be an aficionado of the opera, and I love art museums. 
>
> ...a jazz aficionado.*

You could also use *music aficionado* in your last example:

> He is well-read and his brother is a music aficionado.

I don't believe there is a specific term for songs or even music like *well-read*, at least not in common usage (*Musical* is too broad and not a good fit for your examples, and you've rightly eliminated it before). *Well-listened* comes to mind but it looks like it didn't become an established word and it is not defined in any dictionary, although I've found some examples with relevant usage. Here is an example from a credible source, Princeton Alumni Weekly, Princeton University:

> There is no doubt that Steinberg has read extensively about music and listened extensively to music, **making him both well read and well listened**; in fact, it is unlikely that anyone in the field, past or present (and that includes the great Donald Francis Tovey, who is one of Steinberg's acknowledged role models as a critic and annotator), was, or is, better read or better listened.
>
> [*princeton.edu*](http://www.princeton.edu/%7Epaw/archive_old/PAW98-99/13-0407/0407irtx.html)

You've mentioned that you already know *well-versed* and you are not looking for it; however it is well-worth of consideration as it is commonly used in musical context. Here is an example I've found, specifically used with "songs":

> Krall also boasts an extensive knowledge of the great Tin Pan Alley standards of the twenties, thirties and forties, as well as being uncommonly **well-versed in songs** from the sixties onwards.
>
> [manchestereveningnews.co.uk](https://www.manchestereveningnews.co.uk/whats-on/music/why-diana-krall-rules-1126747)

Answer (score 0):

**melomaniac**

> He is well-read and his brother is a bred-in-the-bone, unrepentant melomaniac.

[**melomaniac**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/melomaniac): a person with a great enthusiasm for music.

Source: Collins Dictionary

Comment: How would you use that word in the OP's sentence about blues songs specifically, as compared to music more generally?

Answer (score 0):

The generic word is "conversant". One may be an aficionado without being conversant. For example, I am an aficionado of Metallica, but I could never remember the title of their songs, or their lyrics (if there is much of any).

e.g., He is conversant with the works of Mozart.

A country music lyric specialist is one who is conversant with the lyrical formula of writing country music lyrics, and therefore would be conversant with the collection of lyrics in country music.

Perhaps we could redundantly reiterate the proficiency by using the term "conversant specialist".

> con·ver·sant  (kən-vûr′sənt, kŏn′vər-)
>
> adj.
> Familiar or knowledgeable, as by study or experience: *conversant with medieval history*.
> [Middle English conversaunt, associated with, from Old French conversant, present participle of converser, to associate with, from Latin conversārī; see converse1.]
> con·ver′sant·ly adv.

American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2016 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.

Answer (score -3):

I like "audio-intellectual." It certainly covers the bases you described, and then some. Hope it works for you.

Comment: But is it a word? It appears in strings like _audio intellectual property_, but that doesn't guarantee that it can be used as a compound adjective.

Comment: @Cerberus You see where allowing unsupported answers gets us?

Comment: Create your own words. Blaze your trail, buddy.